# how to CUT desired sting from shell output with json format

Tags: linux, shell, cut

I am trying to run a shell curl command that produces a json output. From that output I will need to cut a string and send it to new curl command. not getting desired results with cut. please help.

I have output from first curl command as

`"task_id":"abcddfd-dfdfdf-fdfsfsd-fsdfd-fdssff"`

so I am running `cut -f2 -d":"`
and it is giving `"abcddfd-dfdfdf-fdfsfsd-fsdfd-fdssff"` not `abcddfd-dfdfdf-fdfsfsd-fsdfd-fdssff` basically I don't need quotes, just need the task_id value

Please help me with request, Thank you!!!

Comment: `a json output` So use a json parser to parse json output.

Comment: It doesn't look like correct JSON, did you forget opening and closing `{` and `}`?

Comment: That's not JSON, that's *part* of a JSON value and not one you can necessarily assume will be on a line by itself. `curl ... | jq -r '.task_id'`, perhaps.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Sorry, I have not included brackets earlier

Comment: trying to install jq

Comment: @chepner JQ is working if we are passing directly piping it, thank you!!!

Comment: cut -f2 -d":"|sed 's/"//g'  you can use something like this or tr command to remove "

Answer (score 0):

If you have the output with quotes, you can just remove the quotes using the `tr` command -

Try running this - `cut -f2 -d":"|tr -d \"`